Switch off USB power when battery power supply is present
I want to design a circuit that switches off USB power when the battery is present. In other words, the battery power should always take priority. While there are many similar questions on Stack Overflow, I couldn’t find one that meets my specific requirements:

Wide battery voltage range: 3V to 35V (1S–8S).
Do not impede current flow from the battery, such as using diodes.
Minimal PCB footprint (prefer integrated solutions).

I’ve seen circuits using power multiplexers, ORing controllers, which I’ve successfully used before to prioritize between two ~5V sources. But I feel like a fully-featured power multiplexer for two 35V inputs is an overkill here.
Alternatively, circuits where the battery voltage is always higher than VBUS can work with a single FET on the VBUS line. Here’s an example of a circuit using a single MOSFET (for illustrative purposes). However, it won’t work for battery voltages below VBUS.

The closest solution I’ve found is to use an ideal diode or load switch on the VBUS line, such as the LM66100 or TPS22916BL with an active-low ON pin. However, these components have limitations:

They have a fairly low maximum voltage for the ON pin, so I can’t connect the VBAT line directly to it.
Handling VOUT > VIN: It’s unclear how they behave when VOUT exceeds VIN. While they claim to have "reverse current protection," the "activation current" for reverse current blocking is relatively high (e.g., 500mA for the TPS22916BL).

So the question is: how can I design such a circuit while considering my requirements? Does my approach with the TPS22916BL make sense? Should I simply use a voltage divider at the ON pin, and is VOUT > VIN of the TPS22916BL not a concern in my scenario?

You need two back-to-back mosfets to disconnect USB in both directions.
For sensing whether battery is presented use comparator with resistor divider on input.
For driving the gate you can use a photovoltaic isolator:
https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/solid-state-relay/photovoltaic-isolators/

That’s not the neat solution I was hoping for, but apparently, it’s the only one.
